# python slow in socket operations

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server written in JAVA and client written in PYTHON. When I run the client script(it creates 10K clients all sending data infinitely),majority of the time spent is in the socket creation and connection. I have the server running on another system connected through LAN. When I run the JAVA client program, the time taken is 3-6 times less than PYTHON. Is it the problem of python? Or is there any problem in the code?

Here is my program for reference.

```
import array
import os
import sys
import encodings
import subprocess
import datetime
import binascii
import string
import random
import time
import threading
import socket


p=input("Enter the no of client...")
host=raw_input("Enter the host name")
HOST=socket.gethostbyname(host)   
PORT=input("Enter the port no......") 
f1=open("xys.txt","a")
f2=open("string.txt","a")

def id_generator(length,a,b): # generates unique random values between given range
    random.seed()
    while(1):
        x=''.join(random.choice(a+b) for _ in range(length))
        if(a<=x<=b):
            return x

def rand_string():
    a=[]
    s1="29298000280A81D72B150314234153026368560793189500000394F88FD18FFFFF0000001E0000000000000A0D"
    f=open("rule1.txt","r")
    k=f.readline()
    k=k.rstrip('\n')
    if(k=="H"):
        try:
            a=[]
            b=bytearray.fromhex(s1) 
            i=0
            k=f.readline()
            k=k.rstrip('\n') ## reads the no of arguments
            z=int(k)
            n=0
            k=f.readline()
            k=k.rstrip('\n') #reads the delimiter....
            while(n<z):
                k=f.readline()
                k=k.rsplit('\n') # reads the arguments
                c="".join(k) # converting the list to strings
                a=c.rsplit('|') # split the argument
                    # first arg is the index of bit to be changed(e.g. 10 means 11th bit)
                    # second arg is the no of bits to be changed
                    # next is the field name whose value is to be randomized
                    # next is the no of UNIQUE random values to be generated
                    # last two are the range b/w which the value should lie
                i=0
                while(i<int(a[3])):
                    b=bytearray.fromhex(s1)
                    al=''.join(a[4])
                    ah=''.join(a[5])
                    x=id_generator(int(a[1]),al,ah)
                    b1=bytearray.fromhex(x)
                    m=int(a[0])/2
                    l=0
                    while(m<(int(a[0])/2)+int(a[1])/2):
                        b[m]=b1[l]
                        m=m+1
                        l=l+1
                    t=binascii.hexlify(bytearray(b))
                    d=0
                    y=list(t)
                    while(d<len(y)):
                        y[d]=y[d].upper()
                        d=d+1

                    s3=''.join(y)
                    i=i+1

                s1=s3
                n=n+1
            f.close()
            return (s3)

        except Exception:
            return ("sorry")

class procThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,ID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ID=ID

    def run(self):
        try:
            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((HOST,PORT))
        print self.ID,
        print 'Socket'
            t=rand_string()
            s.send(str(t))
            x=t
            while(1):
                t=rand_string()
                x=list(x)
                t=list(t)
                for i in range(10,18):
            t[i]=x[i]

        x=''.join(x)
                s3=''.join(t)
                f2.write(str(self.ID)+'\t'+s3+'\n'+'\n')
                m=s.recv(65536)
                m=binascii.hexlify(bytearray(m))
                f1.write(str(m)+'\n'+'\n')
                t1=threading.Event()
                t1.wait(timeout=float(5))
                s.send(s3)
                i=0

        except socket.error:
            f5=open("ERROR.txt","a")
        f5.write(str(self.ID)+'\n')
            f5.close()



for i in range(1,p+1):
    if((i%100)==0):
        t=threading.Event()
        t.wait(timeout=random.uniform(1,3)+1)

    pt=procThread(i)
    pt.start()
```

Comment: DNS lookup might be slow, have you tried entering the hosts as IP address instead of hostnames?

Comment: It is *very* difficult to determine frmo your code where your hotspot are. I can however assure you that Python is more than capable of saturating even multi Gigabit Ethernet links. (*Probably not with a threading concurrency model though!*)

Comment: Rand_string is very inefficient

Comment: @stark I need to generate a random string every time. Rules for generating the string are in 'rule1.txt'. Any suggestions to optimize?

Comment: Perhaps - you could move out all the file opening and closing out in the `'class procThread'` and get the required values in the class's variable in one go and pass to `rand_string`. Looking at your code, it does look like that's something worth doing. I doubt though - whether it's making this rather slow.

Comment: @gabhijit does s.send() multiple times causing a problem?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge - no. Why are you `wait`ing 5 seconds!! before `send`? Are you sure you are also using the same timeout in Java? By any chance the Java API timeout is not in miliseconds?

Comment: Have you profiled the code?

Comment: And inspite of using **while(1)** ,threads are getting killed.

Comment: Using profiling, the maximum time was in time.sleep() and **acquire** method of threading module. But I haven't use any locks in the program.